# How do I assault city hall

Tags: this-is-the-police

During the final assault on city hall, how should I position my forces to be able to successfully complete the assault?

Comment: Have you tried googling for a walkthrough of the game?

Comment: @Nzall Please don't ever recommend that again. The final goal of Stackexchange is that everyone who googles for a solution to a problem finds a Stackexchange answer as first hit. We want to provide a better collection of answers than all the walkthroughs which can be found on other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force deployment to assault city hall should like this:

- 2 Amphibian assault at the lake (not the dock) (position 1)
- 2 Snipers on the Court house roof (position 6)
- 1 sniper on the Cathedral (position 8)
- 2 Assaulters at city hall on the church side (position 4)
- 1 Assault, 1 Breacher, and the team leader at the back entrance (position 3)
- 1 Breacher, 1 assaulter at the sewer hole  (position 9)